# Toggle org checkbox?

Tags: org-mode

I have the following checklist in `org-mode`:

```
* Delete data for problem days [0/4]
- [ ] task 1 
- [ ] task 2
- [ ] task 3
- [ ] task 4
```

Is there a command for quickly tagging one of these items as done? I'd like to end up with

```
* Delete data for problem days [1/4]
- [X] task 1 
- [ ] task 2
- [ ] task 3
- [ ] task 4
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`org-mode` manual node on "Checkboxes"](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html).  I found this page with a [web search for "org checkbox"](https://www.google.com/search?q=org+checkbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with many things in Org mode, `C-c C-c` is context sensitive and does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `,,` in normal state if you are using the `vim` mode.

Comment: This question was edited not to be spacemacs or evil-mode specific, so I'm going to accept the general answer, but this is very helpful and is actually what answered my original question! :)